DBeaver, how to duplicate a (postgres) schema?
DBeaver is a great tool, but if you "copy" and "paste" a schema it does not include the tables.
If you backup the whole database using the backup tool, restore will overwrite the DB, you cant specify a new database or schema name, which is a significant limitation.   Also backup creates a .sql script, but restore expects a .backup script which is odd.
We cant use database CLI tools as we don't have direct access to the DB (it's RDS).
There is an "export data" option at the table level, but we want to copy the entire schema, not just tables (so include all functions, sequences, views, sequences etc, etc.)

you can use CREAETABLE xyz LIKE see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

I've solved it with dumping data as:
pg_dump -h "localhost" -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -n "source_schema" -f backup.sql --format=p --no-owner --no-privileges --exclude-table-data=source_schema.migrations --data-only
sed -i 's/ source_schema./ #SCHEMANAME_PLACEHOLDER#./g' backup.sql

next restoring it with:
sed 's/ #SCHEMANAME_PLACEHOLDER#./ dest_schema./g backup.sql' > backup.sql.tmp
psql -h "localhost" -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f backup.sql.tmp
rm -rf backup.sql.tmp

Note that I first executed my app logic to create new schema with all migrations/users/access - I needed to duplicate only data, without schema (i.e. structure/shape).
Notes:

If backup's schema (i.e. structure/shape) differs from destination schema a lot then need to catch up everything manually. So such back-ups live not long but for "duplicate/clone" tasks it is enough.
pg_dump and psql are executed with PGPASSWORD=... environment variable.
pg_restore can't be used to restore dump created with "--data-only".
I am excluding "source_schema.migrations" table because it is populated by my app during "apply migration" phase.
Using --format=c --compress=5 instead of --format=p for pg_dump allows to decrease dump size
4.7MB->0.8MB. But there won't be ability to restore it with psql. It would fail with 'Use the pg_restore command-line'.
Used pg_dump version 16.4 for v15 PostgreSQL instance.

